# How do I export a variable name (not the full component) from one component to another in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm finding it hard to export or pass the variable with the names objHead and objDetails from this component to another component so that I can use it there.

is there like a keyword I can use in react for it just like the way module.exports is in Nodejs?

```
function Add(prop){
//function to store the detail and title prop into an object

const AddCart = () => {
       
          const obj = {
                        head:prop.title,
                        body:prop.details
                    }

            const objHead = obj.head;
            const objDetails = obj.body;
    
          

}
    
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="box">
                <h5 id="AddHead">Add header</h5>
                <p>{prop.title}</p>
                <p>{prop.details}</p>
             </div>
             <button className="btn" onClick={AddCart}>Add to cart</button>

             <hr></hr>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Add;
```

Comment: You would have to use context or move the data to the common ancestor of these components.

Comment: How do I do that? Could you give a sample illustration?

Comment: @Kingsley here is a resource on setting up a context hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 0):

Well there are multiple ways to pass a variable from one component to another one , depending on the position of your target components.

-In Case Target Component is Child:
If your target component is being rendered inside the component from where you want to pass variable, then pass it using props.

-In Case Target Component is Parent:
In this case you will store the variable in a state suing usestate hook in parent component, and pass the setter of the state to child component as prop.